# Primefaces 5: wizard and back button

Tags: primefaces, back-button, wizard

I created an example alias following: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml

I need to align on same row of Confirmation tab Back button with Sumbit button. Back button align left, Submit button align rigth, both same row. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by CSS, you can set the position of button. I have just copy past showcase code and run. give same css to submit button as next button and use some cutome css and it work.

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{userWizard.save}" process="@this" styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-wizard-nav-next" 
                style="left: 24px;top: 16px;"/>
```

Note: You may need to adjust the left and top, and check well of css classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your solution is not useful for me because my page must be resizing dynamic. Percentage doesn't work in your solution...

Comment: Can you post some image. for better look.

Comment: i am suppose to use css. any way thanks, can you accept my ans